# What does the graffiti wall of The Magicians mean?

Tags: the-magicians

**The Magicians** has a graffiti wall in the opening scene of each episode. What hidden symbols are there in this graffiti? What does this wall symbolize?

[image: image of the graffiti]

**Edit:-** As @Paulie_D has mentioned in the comment that the graffiti wall changes every season now I want to know that what are the symbols that remain consistent for the 5 seasons for e.g. an octopus-like symbol can be seen always.

Comment: This is too broad really as it changes with every season. - *"The graffiti on the wall in the intro credits undergos several changes at the beginning of every season symbolic of events in the each of the first three seasons. Some features, like the casting hand, the clock that moves, and the Brakebills school seal are in every season. Other features are painted over previous ones. At the beginning of the fourth season, the wall has been painted blank, perhaps symbolic of wiping the memories of the cast who were on the quest for the seven keys."*

Comment: @Paulie_D I was not aware that the wall changed every season I thought that it remained same thanks for pointing that out

Comment: On IMDb, look up each season premiere episode and click on Trivia; you'll find someone's attempt to list that season's new features.  The meaning of each becomes obvious in hindsight: for example if you've watched three seasons I needn't tell you what a moth or a key means.